# OnPrepareOptionsMenu in fragment has different behavior on devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, callback, android-support-library

This code crashes on some devices but works fine on other ones.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    boolean isSelectModeActive = mRecyclerAdapter.getSelectedItemCount() > 0;
    mCallback.onChangeMenuInSelectionMode(menu, isSelectModeActive);
}
```

I attach callback in onAttach method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    try {
        mCallback = (iSongsListFragmentEventListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                                             + " must implement iSongsListFragmentEventListener");
    }
}
```

Stack trace says that mCallback is null in onPrepareOptions method, but why?
I tested this code on my nexus 4 and all emulators - no crashes, but some users got crashes.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void chuprin.serg.com.autotagger.fragments.SongsListFragment$iSongsListFragmentEventListener.onChangeMenuInSelectionMode(android.view.Menu, boolean)' on a null object reference
   at chuprin.serg.com.autotagger.fragments.SongsListFragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu(SongsListFragment.java:292)
```

Comment: Put a null check for your object `mCallback`.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the fragment? Is it in the constructor? Call it from onCreate().

Comment: I call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreate()